# Difference between production and development docker using

Tags: docker

I want to try docker for my web-site. I use `php, nginx, mysql`. I've configured docker and I've run my website locally. Now I want to publish my web-site to production.
I have few difference between developer and production version:

- I need to be able connect to mysql inside container in developer mode (for debugging), but in production mode mysql must be isolated from outside for security
- I want open my web-site by address app.dev and use nginx-proxy image on my developer machine, but on production I will not use nginx-proxy for increase performance.

Could I run docker with one docker-compose.yml file? 
Or should I create two version of docker-compose file for developer and production version? But in this case I lose advantage of docker - same enviroment evrywhere. If I change docker-compose-dev.yml, I need to remember to change docker-compose-prod.yml.

**My docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '2'
services:
    app:
        build: .
        volumes:
         - ./app:/app
        container_name: app
    app_nginx:
        image: nginx
        ports:
         - "8080:80"
        container_name: app_nginx
        volumes:
            - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./app:/app
        environment:
         - VIRTUAL_HOST=app.dev
    app_db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
          - "./data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
            MYSQL_DATABASE: "app_db"
        container_name: app_db  
    nginx-proxy:
        image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
        container_name: nginx-proxy
        ports:
          - "80:80"
        volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with environment variable based configurations.
Usually different environments i.e staging and production differs only by configurations like database it needs to connect to, external service it calls, their end-points and credentials.

Instead of hard coding all such configuration, read them from environment variables. Thus you can use same docker-compose file with different environment variables for your staging and production environment.

You can also explore Rancher by Rancher Labs at http://rancher.com/ to manage your environments.

Comment: But in this case I should ship container and than configure env variables. As far as I understood, main idea of docker is just ship and run without any configuration. Or could I set default values if env variable doesn't exist?

Comment: Docker image will remain the same. It's your application which expects the environment variable based configuration. You can also handle in your application to use production configuration as default if no environment variable is passed. But that would be unsafe as you will be sharing your production credentials with everyone in your team. Docker compose is used to manage your application stack, to launch all dependencies before your main application starts.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. For example, I need map mysql ports 3306:3306 only whem ENV_DEV exists and equals TRUE. What should I do for this?

Create my own mysql:5.7 image based on mysql:5.7 image from docker hub. Than inside my mysql image's dockerfile check variable and expose port if the variable is true, right?

Comment: exposing your container port is part of launching it. You can't make such decision using environment property. What you are trying here is to map port 3306 of your container to your host server.

Comment: Yes I want map port 3306 from container to host machine. But I want do this only on development machine (dev mode). I don't want map any mysql port in production mode. How could I achieve this?

sorry for nooby questions.

Comment: launch your container without ports in your docker-compose. I am not sure of any other way using docker-compose. Try Rancher to maintain your production, then you don't have to maintain multiple docker-compose file